# GooglePayButton in Flutter-Dart: 'Invalid Payment Method' Error when Adding New Credit Card

Tags: android, flutter, google-pay

I'm developing a Flutter-Dart application and using the GooglePayButton for payments. When trying to add a new credit card, I encounter an error message stating "invalid payment method, OR_CCREU_O1". The credit card I'm attempting to add is valid, as I'm able to add and use it in another application successfully, and it allows payments.

Interestingly, when I use another card that's already added to my Google payment methods, the test payment through my app is completed successfully. I'm integrating payments with Stripe and have a developer account associated with both Google Pay and Google Cloud.

I suspect there might be some setting or configuration in Google Pay or Google Cloud that's preventing me from adding a new card. In the Android project, I've configured implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.0.0" and also tried version 19.2.1, though I'm unsure if this is necessary.

Can anyone provide some insights or suggestions to help me resolve this issue?

Below is how I'm calling the GooglePayButton:

```
GooglePayButton(
    paymentConfiguration: googlePayConfig,
    paymentItems: const [
    PaymentItem(
      label: 'Total',
      amount: '2.00',
      status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
    )
    ],
    type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
    onPaymentResult: (result) {
    // log(result.toString());
    String res = result.toString();              
    },
    onError: (error) {                
    },
    loadingIndicator: const Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
),
```

Below are the configurations and the error:

[image]

configuration
[image]

Versions

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.16.7 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ef1af02aea (7 weeks ago) • 2024-01-11 15:19:26 -0600
Engine • revision 4a585b7929
Tools • Dart 3.2.4 • DevTools 2.28.5


Dart SDK version: 3.2.4 (stable) (Thu Dec 21 19:13:53 2023 +0000) on "windows_x64"
```

Android configs

file :  ...\android\app\build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"

    // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {

 
    namespace "com.xxxx"    
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug            
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.2.1'    
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.37.4'
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))    
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
}
```

android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="xxxxxxx"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
                        
            android:theme="@style/NormalTheme"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                        
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="xxxxxxx"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
            android:value="true"/>


    </application>

    <queries>        
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>        
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>        
         <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

android\build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android\settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false    
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
    }
}

include ":app"

apply from: "${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with your Google Pay integration (still please make sure to use the latest play-services-wallet SDK 19.2.1) - could you go to https://payments.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/paymentmethods and try to add your credit card there? what happens if you do this?

Comment: I'm able to insert the same credit card that I tested in the app.

Comment: Alright. Now please delete the card again from https://payments.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/paymentmethods and try to re-add from the "Add credit or debit" card screen within Google Pay

Comment: I only removed this card, and I tried to use it in the app, but it still gives the same error.

I have 2 credit cards on GPay, 1 is associated with Google Cloud and I cannot remove it, the other one I removed.

I had already seen this solution of removing the cards, but since I can't remove the last one because it's associated with Cloud ... I've included my configuration files and versions in the post

Comment: I guess the same thing happens here: https://gpay-live-demo.web.app/ - correct?

Comment: correct! , yes the same error shows up

Comment: yeah so it is an issue with your card and not with your Google Pay integration code. Could you file a support request from the Pay & Wallet console? https://pay.google.com/business/console

Comment: Yes, I'll do it tomorrow. Thanks for your assistance!